# Wrapfigure "wrap box" continues onto next page

Tags: wrapfigure

I'm using the wrapfigure environment.  When the wrapfigure goes to the bottom of the page, there is blank space included on the next page where the figure would be.  The problem is illustrated in the attached figure and mwe.  How do I fix this?

[image: The problem: the caption goes to the end of the page (fine), but blank space continues onto the next page (not cool)]

I have prepared a mwe, but it's not very minimal (needed to be multiple pages to show the problem).  If you want to compile this, you'll need to replace the .pdf file with some figure of your choice.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

"Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur,
adipisci velit..." "There is no one who loves pain itself, who seeks after it
and wants to have it, simply because it is pain..."



Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque et dui quis
velit sollicitudin egestas. Phasellus dictum, libero sed pellentesque pulvinar,
lectus arcu fermentum libero, vel ultricies augue eros vel ligula. Proin tempor
velit id dolor sollicitudin pharetra. Duis consectetur metus et quam congue
commodo vitae et velit. Quisque laoreet nibh ac lorem porta id vulputate lorem
vestibulum. In condimentum nulla convallis orci commodo sit amet scelerisque
tortor dapibus. Nam rhoncus, ipsum ut adipiscing ullamcorper, libero odio
vehicula neque, ut sagittis turpis velit vitae velit. Ut sit amet ipsum ac leo
cursus dictum vel eget augue. Proin non sapien felis. Aenean nec volutpat est.
Morbi feugiat velit sed leo laoreet mattis.

Etiam blandit metus ut dui posuere vehicula. Donec id eros at enim vestibulum
feugiat. Duis quam est, malesuada sagittis porttitor pretium, lacinia vel
augue. Aliquam at eros purus, eu tempus sem. Ut iaculis, augue et accumsan
tempus, sem tortor rhoncus massa, at imperdiet tellus elit eget urna.
Pellentesque risus leo, congue in imperdiet id, interdum id ante. Pellentesque
convallis varius mattis. Suspendisse potenti. In auctor faucibus rhoncus.
Vestibulum scelerisque malesuada metus, eu ultricies urna posuere vel. Etiam in
sem eu mi semper condimentum at eget quam. Nullam libero dolor, tristique eget
tristique id, gravida ut nisi. Nam ornare mi et est hendrerit gravida fringilla
sapien suscipit. Etiam erat purus, porttitor nec bibendum venenatis, elementum
ac urna.

Praesent pulvinar imperdiet ipsum in placerat. Ut euismod purus quis libero
iaculis egestas. Integer vel erat eros, tincidunt viverra orci. Integer ante
risus, consectetur quis lacinia at, varius ut lorem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum porttitor orci in ligula
imperdiet id lobortis nulla viverra. Nulla eget enim vitae purus placerat
malesuada. Maecenas tincidunt mattis magna, sit amet gravida mi feugiat eu.
Vestibulum sed diam nulla. Proin velit augue, posuere vitae cursus non,
lobortis sed nibh. Nullam aliquet molestie ante, at dictum libero posuere eget.
Fusce a libero ac odio vestibulum malesuada. Curabitur luctus nunc in leo
sagittis ut pretium leo egestas. Morbi vel ligula ligula. Donec nulla ipsum,
placerat id posuere ut, condimentum sit amet augue.

Nunc vitae venenatis felis. Ut orci eros, commodo vitae rutrum vel, ultrices id
orci. Aliquam egestas velit eget tortor dignissim eu aliquam neque viverra.
Morbi sodales rhoncus feugiat. Ut ac erat et nisl adipiscing ornare porttitor
fringilla est. Donec eleifend metus et nulla ultricies ultricies suscipit quam
euismod. Suspendisse potenti. Nullam eget tristique erat. Fusce sed vestibulum
quam. Vivamus aliquam, urna vel mattis dapibus, nisi lacus hendrerit est, vitae
venenatis ipsum nisi vitae lectus. Integer laoreet enim non metus aliquet
sagittis. Nam semper consequat eros, id ultricies risus placerat non.

Donec risus nunc, porttitor id placerat sit amet, varius nec libero. Cras vel
dolor magna. Aenean dui ante, posuere in vehicula sed, mattis viverra mi.
Integer quis orci et eros gravida consequat nec quis metus. Donec dictum augue
quam. Praesent neque urna, laoreet eget lobortis quis, pretium sit amet neque.
Donec egestas molestie neque, vel egestas enim luctus eu. Nullam diam magna,
suscipit ac ornare vel, vehicula et lectus. Ut eu mi mi. Morbi blandit, leo in
tincidunt posuere, ante nisl dictum justo, vitae feugiat erat sapien quis dui.
Duis lacus libero, fermentum nec malesuada sed, elementum eu nisl. Integer
aliquam metus a lacus tincidunt condimentum. Pellentesque pulvinar porttitor
tristique. Cras ante dui, volutpat vel lacinia iaculis, accumsan a tellus.
Etiam risus quam, sodales volutpat feugiat vel, euismod ut odio.

Duis porttitor lacus urna, vel blandit turpis. Vivamus gravida ultrices nulla
in viverra. Aliquam vulputate posuere ipsum, ut porta quam consequat eget.
Etiam pulvinar, quam sed auctor semper, metus sapien consequat dolor, id
interdum ante nisi id tellus. Nulla iaculis augue quis lacus hendrerit quis
euismod mauris gravida. Fusce eu neque et tellus aliquet vulputate nec ut
magna. Aenean pharetra molestie lacus nec aliquam. Cras at ultrices augue. Sed
venenatis, risus vel gravida accumsan, metus dui blandit enim, nec sollicitudin
magna ligula at nibh. Sed elementum ipsum vitae odio facilisis feugiat. Vivamus
ac felis est. Etiam massa nunc, imperdiet in porttitor non, placerat sit amet
felis. Sed elit urna, scelerisque non rhoncus id, consequat id tortor.

Quisque adipiscing fermentum dui, in vehicula nibh facilisis convallis. Cras
condimentum adipiscing eros, nec tempor justo consectetur placerat. Sed
accumsan, lacus id rhoncus consectetur, libero orci euismod erat, non
sollicitudin arcu orci quis velit. Curabitur vitae sollicitudin diam. Duis
hendrerit augue sit amet orci dictum in mattis augue volutpat. Vivamus nec
sagittis tellus. Etiam felis felis, pretium sed luctus ac, euismod vitae nisl.
Phasellus vestibulum, odio sed condimentum ultrices, enim ante interdum nisi,
id sodales augue lectus vitae massa. Curabitur non convallis velit. Etiam eget
diam et nisi euismod vehicula. Donec dignissim, nisi vitae porta scelerisque,
felis leo sodales mauris, quis condimentum purus turpis dapibus arcu. Mauris
molestie fermentum risus sit amet lacinia. Maecenas sollicitudin mollis purus
ut consectetur. Maecenas et ligula quam. Morbi eget diam nisi, sed luctus arcu.

Praesent id libero ante, nec dapibus dolor. Vivamus egestas, nunc id malesuada
mollis, nisl neque condimentum lorem, non accumsan enim lorem ac neque. Morbi
in ligula magna, vehicula interdum metus. Sed eget lorem nec nibh ornare
suscipit eu nec nunc. Nulla est diam, tempus vitae egestas vitae, egestas vel
dui. Integer ac libero diam. Mauris sit amet arcu eu neque feugiat iaculis.
Aenean non nulla eu erat malesuada fringilla sed non justo. Curabitur non
libero orci, et egestas elit. Sed gravida est sit amet ligula pretium non
volutpat purus dictum. Quisque eros leo, consectetur vulputate hendrerit vitae,
semper sed est. Sed malesuada luctus massa sed posuere. Quisque blandit orci
nec libero placerat varius. Donec luctus nulla eu sapien consectetur sit amet
scelerisque turpis hendrerit. Fusce sed mi augue.

Donec tristique, ante nec rhoncus auctor, sapien lacus varius metus, eu
vulputate metus sem ac justo. Pellentesque arcu orci, tempor consequat luctus
pretium, elementum quis augue. Fusce tincidunt varius molestie. Nam ac velit ut
est fermentum porttitor. Etiam vel lobortis justo. In aliquet consequat elit
eget rutrum. Mauris non eros ligula, eget ultrices sapien.

Quisque egestas, libero eu venenatis faucibus, orci massa molestie ante, et
aliquet enim nisi vitae elit. Suspendisse ultricies sagittis mauris. Vestibulum
ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;
Nam quis turpis at est imperdiet accumsan. Aenean sed venenatis magna. Morbi
viverra dui sed lacus semper sed convallis tortor eleifend. Vestibulum at erat
sapien. Donec eget sagittis neque. Vestibulum in interdum urna.

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.5\textwidth}
    {\includegraphics[scale=0.4,angle=0,width=3.5in]{MassiveStarHR.pdf}}
    \caption{blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
    blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
    blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
    blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
    blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
    blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
    blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
    blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah }
    \label{fig:hr}
\end{wrapfigure}


Nullam cursus bibendum magna. Aliquam id nisi nisi. In lobortis ultrices sapien
id suscipit. Vestibulum ut arcu id lectus pretium eleifend. Duis dui urna,
aliquam id malesuada eget, dictum ut ligula. Phasellus venenatis odio a ligula
dictum ut pellentesque tellus tincidunt. Cras sed feugiat nulla. Curabitur
varius vestibulum nisi. Nulla sit amet purus sed eros euismod vulputate.
Suspendisse faucibus risus turpis, ut aliquet purus.

Aenean a erat at mi mollis elementum semper sit amet magna. Donec pretium
mauris at lorem pulvinar elementum. Suspendisse in quam ut turpis cursus
imperdiet eu et justo. Curabitur iaculis nulla ac magna semper luctus. Lorem
ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam nec eros orci, et
egestas tortor. Nullam ac odio sit amet est volutpat lacinia. Suspendisse leo
nibh, fringilla ac lacinia sit amet, tincidunt sed lorem. Mauris eu lacus et
lectus pellentesque blandit in eget purus. Proin vel dui erat, ut aliquet quam.
Pellentesque vitae elit vel mi venenatis tempus.

Vivamus id augue diam. Sed consequat aliquam risus, id accumsan turpis suscipit
a. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames
ac turpis egestas. Maecenas fringilla odio at dui accumsan consectetur.
Maecenas non risus vel mi pulvinar bibendum quis ac magna. Mauris et hendrerit
enim. Sed et sem id felis eleifend ornare.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam a sagittis enim.
Donec ac erat ac nulla mollis mollis. Curabitur urna turpis, porta nec
elementum sed, ornare nec leo. In facilisis ipsum nunc, eget suscipit odio.
Vestibulum tincidunt velit nec magna sodales fringilla faucibus eget eros.
Curabitur pulvinar ante interdum turpis dignissim dapibus. Donec ultricies
suscipit enim ac blandit. Nunc eu lectus vel metus volutpat bibendum. Sed a
purus est. Mauris faucibus nulla eu mi convallis vel suscipit nibh dignissim.

Nulla porttitor iaculis sodales. Praesent convallis arcu quis magna suscipit
suscipit. Curabitur congue tortor eget ligula consequat in commodo tellus
pharetra. Vestibulum neque erat, gravida non faucibus non, ultricies a nibh.
Mauris sem lacus, varius in imperdiet et, sollicitudin ut nisl. Sed porttitor,
velit ut posuere mattis, odio purus condimentum urna, id aliquet nisl nulla ut
mi. Sed vulputate porttitor purus et pretium. Fusce rutrum convallis nibh,
varius fringilla lectus ullamcorper a. Morbi purus odio, tristique aliquet
vestibulum sed, iaculis vel quam. Quisque dictum, nunc quis aliquam iaculis,
lorem est fermentum nibh, eget luctus nibh lorem sed sapien. Sed in commodo
ligula. Suspendisse tempus nisi ac massa aliquam blandit. Vestibulum libero
augue, scelerisque eget rutrum fringilla, euismod non nibh. Nullam venenatis
velit non erat tempus sit amet pulvinar ligula tristique. In vulputate dapibus
est a convallis.


\end{document}
```

Comment: You're unlucky. :( Try reducing the figure height or the caption length. If the object doesn't fit on the page, there's nothing that you can do (unless you can use `\enlargethispage`)

Comment: another option would be to horizontally enlarge the figure, e.g., use `.6\textwidth`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on the desired result, you have two possibilities: if the figure must remain in the position in which it appears in the code, you can try using `\enlargethispage` somewhere in the page where the figure appears (as **egreg** mentioned in a comment); for example:

```
\enlargethispage{2\baselineskip}
```

Another option that helps (and certainly works in the particular case of the minimal example given), is to allow the figure to float (of course now the figure will be moved most probably to the next page); in this case, you should use `L` instead of `l`; the uppercased variants of the placement specifiers allow the figure to float (the lowecase versions mean "put the figure here"):

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{L}{0.5\textwidth}
    {\includegraphics[scale=0.4,angle=0,width=3.5in]{MassiveStarHR.pdf}}
    \caption{blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
    blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
    blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
    blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
    blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
    blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
    blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
    blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah }
    \label{fig:hr}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

The list of specifiers in their two-folded versions are:

- `r`, `R` - right side of the text.
- `l`, `L` - left side of the text.
- `i`, `I` - inside edge–near the binding (if [twoside] document).
- `o`, `O` - outside edge–far from the binding.

Answer (score 1):

I know this solution might not be the prettiest, but I thought I'd mention that the Wikibook on LaTeX's Floats and Figures [mentions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Tip_for_figures_with_too_much_white_space) a solution to the problem, which solved the problem for me (neither `\enlargethispage` and capitalising the control letters worked for me):

Simply add a `\vspace{-Xpt}` below the caption.  I realise this is not a pretty solution, as it has to be tailored for each figure manually (and must be altered whenever the caption is changed or the figure moved), but it does the trick as a last resort.

Comment: I added this answer in case someone else stumbles upon this question like I did.